# Surface Normal from Cross Product

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Given an equation (in this case $x^2-y^2+z=0$) how would I find the surface normal using a cross product at a certain $(1,2,3)$ point? I know how do it with $grad(f)$ but I presume that isn't what they're asking me to do in this case?

I then have to find the equation of the tangent plane at the same point but that would just involve finding $ax+by+cz=d$ wouldn't it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can parametrize the surface by the function $G(x,y) = (x,y,y^2 - x^2)$. Then you can cross $G_x = \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$ with $G_y = \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}$ which are both parallel to the tangent plane to give you a normal.